# javascript navigating child elements in this context saved to var

Tags: javascript

suppose I have the following html

```
<div class="mytable">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  <table>
</div>
<div class="mytable">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  <table>
</div>
```

which I address with the following code:

```
$('.mytable').each(function(){
    var that = $(this);
});
```

Now I need to get **tr** elements inside my tables. How can I do that? I tried something like:

```
$(that+'>tr')
```

but it obviously did not work(( Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try `that.find('tr')`

Comment: I suggest you read [this JQuery tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) which explains the concepts involved

Comment: and how about ids and classes inside? Is it possible to use something like $(that.find('#myid'))?

Comment: Yes `that.find('#myid')`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<body>` element isn't allowed inside a `<table>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to @NenadVracar comment you can try using:

```
$('.mytable').each(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    var $tr = that.find('tr');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('div > tr')` would work if `tr` was a direct child of `div`, which is obviously not the case...

In your question, you talk about *context*. This word is actually appropriate in jQuery because it is a formal concept of the library.

`.find()` is a valid solution, of course. However, you could simplify even more using the optional `context` parameter of the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) function. If you do not see what I mean, look at this code:

```js
$('tr', '.mytable').each(function () {
  var $tr = $(this);
  console.log($tr.attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mytable">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="tr1"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="mytable">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="tr2"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

`$('tr', '.mytable')` means that you want to select `tr` elements within `.mytable` elements. If you only need `tr` elements from your tables, this is a decent alternative to `.find()`.